# NodeJS APIs folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am going to have multiple APIs in routes folder should I put them in in the same file API or separate them?

```
├── app.js
├── src/
│   ├── contants/
│   ├── helpers/
│   ├── models/
│   ├── routes/
|   |         |___index.js
              |___api.js
│   └── libs/
│       ├── backbone/
│       ├── underscore/
│       └── ...
```

```
api.js file contains all the APIs
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
    const axios = require("axios")
    require("express-async-errors")
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
    const fs = require("fs")

    const LOLTrackingSystem = require("../methods/onlineGamesTracking/LOLTracking")
    const getUserData = require("../methods/leagueOfLegends/getUserData")
    const isAuthenticated = require("../helpers/authenticated")

    const apiRoute = (api) => {
      api.use(bodyParser.json())
      api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
      }));

      api.post("/api/auth", (req, res) => {
        //API Functions
      })

      api.post("/api/gizmo/memberProfile", isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
        //API Functions
      })

      api.post("/api/gizmo/memberState/:userId/:host/:state", async (req, res) => {
        //API Functions
      })
    }

    module.exports = apiRoute
```

Is what I am doing is right?

If it's wrong what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no right in wrong in this situation it's a question of what's best for your particular situation if you are going to build many Rest API endpoints it's best to separate them in separate files under routes like this so your code can be more maintainable :

```
│   ├── routes/
|   |         |___index.js
              |___auth.js
              |___gizmo.js
                          -
```